# how to write jpa query? in repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Zap.png)
this img is user table and example tuple
here,

I want to use sql query "SELECT MAX(KEY_NAME) FROM USER;" and right here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEmDG.png)
So in java, I wrote jpa query but I met ERROR 16148

> 2023-02-01 20:58:51.668 ERROR 16148 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type specified for TypedQuery [gdsc.toypj.dutchpayit.domain.User] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [gdsc.toypj.dutchpayit.domain.User] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Long]] with root cause

here my source

UserRepository.java

```java
public User findOneUser() {
    return em.createQuery("select MAX(r.id) from User r", User.class)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

User.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "key_name")
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Menu> menuList = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

public static User addUser(String name){
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    return user;
}
```

UserService.java

```java
@Transactional
public User OneUser(){
    User user = userRepository.findOneUser();
    return user;
}
```

UserController.java

```java
@GetMapping("/get/one")
public ResponseEntity getOneUser(){

    User user = userService.OneUser();
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new SuccessResponse(200,user));

}
```

I've been trying more than 3 hours..

in UserRepository.java, I tried them and error in everything.

em.createQuery("select MAX(r.Key_name) from User r", User.class)

em.createQuery("select id from User", User.class)

oh this is worked

```java
return em.createQuery("select r from User r", User.class)
.getResultList();
```

why only "select r" is working I don't know!!!!

Comment: should be: createQuery("select MAX(r.id) from User r", **Long.class**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the TypedQuery defined to return the `User` object.

You can try and change the TypedQuery to `Long` or create another query that will return the User as an object.

You can go with something similar like this:

```sql
select r from User r where r.id = (select MAX(r.id) from User r)
```